# Accessing a m2m field values in django templates using forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Please help me in accessing the m2m values in the templates using forms

My Models:

```
class Opportunity(models.Model):
    sfdc_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)

class Event(models.Model):
    background = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    opportunities = models.ManyToManyField(Opportunity, null=True, blank=True)
```

Views.py

```
def event(request,event_id):
    if request.method == 'GET' :
        eventForm=EventForm(instance=Event.objects.get(pk=event_id))
        locationForm = LocationForm(prefix='location')
        return render(request,'events/event.html', {'eventForm': eventForm, 'locationForm': locationForm})
```

Updated the Model Form:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    account = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.all())
    background = CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-textarea resizeoff auto-resize js_auto_resize  default'}), required=False)
    opportunities = CharField(label='SalesForce ID', widget=TextInput(attrs={'class' : 'form-input'}), required=False)
```

In My Template I have tried following code, but not working

```
{% for attr in eventForm.opportunities.all %}
      <td>{{ attr.sfdc_id }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried this and still not working

```
{% for attr in eventForm.opportunities_set.all %}
      <td>{{ attr.sfdc_id }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

> Please help me!!!

Comment: You should show us the definition of EventForm  and LocationForm

Comment: I have updated the model form, please have a look @Alvaro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your form, change the definition of opportunities to:

```
class EventForm(ModelForm):
    account = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Account.objects.all())
    background = CharField(widget=Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-textarea resizeoff auto-resize js_auto_resize  default'}), required=False)
    opportunities = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Opportinuty.objects.all(), label='SalesForce ID', required=False)
```

Docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelmultiplechoicefield)

This will render a proper M2M form control.
If, you wish to change the widget to a more usable one, I suggest looking at [django-selectable](https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-selectable/)

It has a nice [AutocomboboxSelectMultipleWidget](https://django-selectable.readthedocs.org/en/v0.8.X/widgets.html#autocomboboxselectmultiplewidget) that I find quite useful (and nice!)

Comment: I want to keep the opportunities field as text box, because the need is the users can enter new values to opportunities while editing the event form .

Comment: The widget I showed you lets you add new values on the fly, but in case you want to use the textfield, you need to process the form manually

Comment: yes, I am processing the values manually, Here is the code that I was doing the manual processing. http://dpaste.com/hold/1566046/

Comment: Then I would add a context variable: opportunities_list = opportunities.split(',') ; and render it manually

Comment: So, it means there is no other to access it in the templates?

Comment: The way I've done this is to add a the M2Ms into the context on the view. Then add an autocomplete to the text field.

Comment: @Alvaro as you suggested, I have passed the opportunities_list in my view as context variable and manually rendered in the template!!

Answer (score 1):

```
opportunities = ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=SelectMultiple(attrs={'class' : 'form-input'}),queryset=Opportinuty.objects.all(), label='SalesForce ID', required=False)
```

...